# Conda stopped working with the debug feature in visual studio code for no apparent reason

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

### To note:

- Pressing F5 (start debugging) **correctly activates** the conda environment
- The environment of the IDE is indeed the desired conda environment. **Python 3.9.7 ('conda environment name': conda)**
- The conda environment **works** if done through the terminal instead of the F5 debugging feature

After the environment is activated and I press F5 nothing happens and nothing is logged to the visual studio code logs. It does not work with any conda environment I have including 'base'.

This is the only thing that happens when I press F5:

[image]

Starts debugging, as expected.

One / two seconds later:

[image]

If I change the code interpreter to just Python 3.9.7 the code does in fact run. And again, if I run the conda enviroment *THROUGH* the terminal instead of F5 (and giving up on debugging, which I need) the conda enviroment also works.

To reiterate, no debug logs in Visual Studio Code, including files.

Any idea on how to tackle this? Been stuck for a while.

Machine is an ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with VS Code ([issue link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18436)). Apparently, it was supposed to be fixed, but it still wasn't working for me. The issue was with new the new Python extension and older versions of Conda.

So first of all try updating Conda. For me it still wasn't working because VS Code didn't have the appropriate permissions, so I had to launch it with admin rights. Now it works.